# In angular js why does this javascript replace method to replace &nbsp works on the controller side but not on the template side

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Template angular expression:

```
<h2 style="white-space:normal">
    {{notification.noti_val.replace(/\&nb\s*sp;/g, ' ')}}
</h2>
```

does not work

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.notification = 'ujjal saha&nbsp;share&nbsp;own&nbsp;wall';
    $scope.notif = notification.noti_val.replace(/\&nb\s*sp;/g, '') 
}
```

works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work because `angular expressions` are not exactly same as `javascript expressions`. In your example you are trying to create a `regular expression` and evaluate it. As mentioned on [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) `angular expressions` do not allow `No RegExp Creation With Literal Notation`. And since angularjs expressions are `forgiving` no error is thrown but your code doesn't work silently

Comment: Thank you very much Aditya.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a filter? As stated by @AdityaSingh above, angular expressions are not exactly like JavaScript expressions, which is why filters were created.

JS:

```
angular.module('MODULE_NAME').filter('stripSpaces', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return input.replace(/\&nb\s*sp;/g, '');
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
{{notification.noti_val | stripSpaces}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code closely.

```
$scope.notification = 'ujjal saha&nbsp;share&nbsp;own&nbsp;wall';
$scope.notif = notification.noti_val.replace(/\&nb\s*sp;/g, '');
```

You have `$scope.notification =` but later try to edit `notification.noti_val`

Comment: That was just a typo mistake.I edited it.Anyways thanks for your time.Much appreciated.